# VS Code Showing Code Problem With Angular Reactive Form Control

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, angular-forms

I am getting a code problem highlighted by Angular Language Service as showing that I Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input.

I have double checked that the reactive forms module is registered in the app.module but I just cannot find why it's not recognising it.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { TimetableListComponent } from './components/timetable-list/timetable-list.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guards/auth-guard.service';
import { TimetablesService } from './services/timetables/timetables.service';
import { UserService } from './services/users/user.service';
import { GenericService } from './services/generic/generic.service';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    TimetableListComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    TimetablesService,
    GenericService,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  
  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  passwordFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);

}
```

login.component.html

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>zz</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input  type="email" matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com" name="userEmailAddress" >
          <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter a valid email address
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Email is <strong>required</strong>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

I have reviewed all known problems that I could find and a lot of the information suggests that the reactive module isn't being imported. I am pretty sure that I am doing that correctly.

Comment: try: close vscode - restart it. If it not help: delete node_modules, run `npm install`. restart with `ng serve`. Your code looks fine

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was a really silly mistake. I had VS code installed in the User mode so it wasn't updating and the Angular language service then wasn't updating because of that.

Updated both and it's now working fine. Just posting here incase someone else has this issue